# watch does not triggered in mounted function in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am using vue.js. I want to watch a variable. But this variable is changed in mounted function ... but this watch is not triggered at all in the mounted function

```
isPromiseLoading: {
    '1PromiseCheck': false,
    '2PromiseCheck': false,
    '3PromiseCheck': false,
    '3PromiseCheck': false,
    '4PromiseCheck': false
  }
```

Here is the isPromiseLoading. because I have super complicated Axios getting data. that is why I am using it to check if all the data are loaded. There are four places that have to be checked.
in the watch function is isPromiseLoading watched to check if all checks are true. If all checks are true then stop loading (which means data are loaded)

```
watch: {isPromiseLoading(){
console.info(1)
}
```

In the mounted function, when one Axios is loaded, then change one check to true. the following is one of check example:

```
Promise.all(facilitiesPromises).then((response) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          this.allFacilitiesInfo[this.allFacilitiesWithCoordinates[i].id] = response[i].data
          this.allSuppliers[this.allFacilitiesWithCoordinates[i].id] = this.allFacilitiesWithCoordinates.filter((value) =>
            response[i].data.suppliers.includes(value.id)
          )
          this.isPromiseLoading['1PromiseCheck'] = true
        }
      })
```

I have 4 places to change isPromiseLoading, then it should show 4 times 1 in console.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61911167/vue-how-to-watch-inner-values-of-json-data/61911235#61911235

Comment: How about using the `immediate` properties: `watch: { isPromiseLoading: { handler(newVal, oldVal){ ... }, immediate: true, deep: true } }` ?